# After theme change the menus have to be manually linked to the corresponding theme location

Tags: theme-development, menus

When publishing a new version of a theme after I upload and select the new version of the theme the menus aren't visible on the site anymore. Everytime I have to link them to the corresponding [theme location](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus) in order to get them working again.

Is there a way I can 'hard code' these menu's so I won't have to do this manual step everytime?

Comment: Why would you need to select it again if it's same theme? What is your process exactly, is switching to some third theme involved?

Comment: I upload a new version of the theme so I upload a new folder to the ftp. And then in theme selection I select the currently uploaded theme.

Answer (score 0):

Each theme has difference "theme location", so when you change the theme, the "theme location" will change too. That mean there is no way you can hard code those menu to "theme location". (That's all I know)